# #perfectMatchings is self-reducible

Tags: complexity-theory, counting

How can one show that the counting problem:

Given a  graph, output the number of perfect matchings

Is self reducible?

I found a hint in Moore's Chapter on Counting, Sampling and Statistical Physics:

> Let G be a graph and e one of its edges. Show that we can modify G to
> produce two graphs, G0 and G1, such that the number of perfect matchings
> of G that include and exclude e is the number of perfect matchings of
> G1 and G0 respectively.

But I could not come up with a proof. The main question here is: How can we proof self-reducability of #perfectMatchings?

Aside: I don't know of a formal definition of self-reduciability. I just know the intuitive phrasing "partially solving the problem results in a smaller problem of the same kind". But is there a formal definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count all perfect matchings containing an edge $e = (x,y)$, simply remove both endpoints $x,y$. To count all perfect matching not containing the edge $e$, simply remove the edge.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Just that I got the notion of self-reducibility correct: As in both cases, the number of edges decreases by at least 1, it is self-reducible?

Comment: Self-reducibility is a somewhat informal notion, though there might be formalizations floating around in some papers.